# How to provide API clients with up-to-date validation rules for an endpoint?

Tags: json, forms, api, validation

In our API we want to implement solution which will allow clients pull validation rules. It will be useful to synchronize validation rules and any helpful text under fields like "Your password should be 8-100 symbols".

For example, when client request validation rules for registration, API responses with this JSON:

```
{
  "email": {
    "html5type": "email",
    "maxlength": 255,
    "required": true
  },
  "phone": {
    "html5type": "tel",
    "minlength": 11,
    "maxlength": 11,
    "pattern": "[0-9]{11}",
    "required": true
  },
  "username": {
    "html5type": "text",
    "minlength": 5,
    "maxlength": 18,
    "pattern": "[a-z0-9_]{5,18}",
    "required": true
  },
  "password": {
    "html5type": "password",
    "minlength": 8,
    "maxlength": 100,
    "required": true
  },
  "birthday": {
    "html5type": "date",
    "required": false
  }
}
```

The question is about best format to request this data. We've thought about 3 ways.

### 1. Query parameter

Client should add `?rules` parameter to endpoint and send request.

So these two requests will have different behavior:

- `POST /v1/register-account` — creates account.
- `POST /v1/register-account?rules` — just responses with rule list for each field.

But I don't really sure this is elegant way to implement this feature. In our project we will implement this feature for filters too (I mean client will be able to get validation rules for filters). So I think it will look a bit ugly in cases like this:

- `GET /v1/products?vendor=33` — list products of 33's vendor.
- `GET /v1/products?rules` — get validation rules for all available filters.

But my colleague likes this way.

### 2. `Accept` header

Another idea is to allow client set custom `application/rules+json` MIME type in `Accept` header which will be prioritized by the API and if API meets this MIME type in this header it will respond with validation rules.

But we don't really like this idea because `Accept` header should only modify representation (format) of response. I mean if you want response in XML, you add `application/xml` to the header; if you want in JSON — you set it equals to `application/json`. However this idea with custom MIME type is not about representation, it's absolutely another sort of data!

### 3. Another endpoint

A way I personally like is another endpoint. When client sends `GET /v1/rules?endpoint=/v1/register-account&method=POST` API simply responses with validation rules for given endpoint.

---

I want to know your opinion. Which way will you choose and why? Maybe you know another good ways that are not listed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) is a widely-accepted vocabulary for validating JSON data. It would be best if you use this rather than your own.

Because JSON Schema is popular, many validators exist in different programming languages. Using a JSON schema validator, clients can easily validate their data against your JSON schema.

As for the endpoint, you can simply use the `OPTIONS` HTTP method. So `OPTIONS /v1/register-account` should return the requirements (including the schema) for using that endpoint. See [this article](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html) as an example.