# REST request validation rules for a model

Tags: rest, validation, web-applications, web-development-server

I am writing a REST API and a WEB on top.  I would really like the API to provide the WEB with validation and default value information for input models.

Here is a fictional example:

```
{
  "name": "string",   // 1 to 50 characters.
  "gender": "string", // Must be one of 'Male', 'Female', 'Legal Entity'
  "BirthYear": "int"  // [1900, 2019] - Default 1999
  "weight": "decimal" // numeric(10, 2) Precision=10, Scale=2
  "deceased": "bool"  // Default = false.
}
```

I know I can use EnumDataType to list enumerations in Swagger but sometimes I have dynamic enumerations based on values in the database.  Gender could for example be dynamic as people identify with new genders all the time :)

So in REST is there a known pattern how to pass such information to the client from the API for example via the OPTION verb?

Can anyone point to a good article or information about something like this?

Comment: The following is a similar question, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816325/how-to-provide-api-clients-with-up-to-date-validation-rules-for-an-endpoint

Comment: OK I like this, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate the type and if the field is not empty, if the genre does not exist in the database, you throws a 422 status code, that indicate a semantical error (the client wanna POST/UPDATE with right media type,  a right syntax , but uncorrect semantical value).

The optional method according to [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is used to view what resource or sever support(allowed methods and headers for example):

> The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options
>   for the target resource.

Comment: I do server validation and return 422 when appropriate.  Using only this however makes for poor UX and I would like to guide the UI for better UX.  For example tell the UI how many decimal places a decimal should have and which enum values are available.